# Using multiple colors within a label

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the chart below, I'm looking to have each triangle in the label for subgroup A match the color of the subgroup they are referring to (green, blue, purple). Is this possible at all?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

example_tibble <- tibble(Subgroup = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                         Result = c(0.288, 0.204, 0.206, 0.182),
                         A_vs_B = rep(1, 4),
                         A_vs_C = rep(1, 4),
                         A_vs_D = rep(1, 4))

ggplot(example_tibble, aes(x = Subgroup, y = Result, fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_text(aes(label = 
      paste0(percent(Result), 
             if_else(A_vs_B == 1 & Subgroup == "A", sprintf("\u25b2"), ""),
             if_else(A_vs_C == 1 & Subgroup == "A", sprintf("\u25b2"), ""),
             if_else(A_vs_D == 1 & Subgroup == "A", sprintf("\u25b2"), "")),
             colour = Subgroup), hjust = -.25) + 
  coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,.5), labels = percent)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can make one multicolored label. If you split it in four or use `geom_point`, yes.